# MSBuild exist condition for Linux/Ubuntu case-sensitive file systems

Tags: msbuild, .net-standard-2.0

Our solution has targetframework .NetStadndard 2.0 and is run on Linux\Ubuntu as well as on Windows.

We have a json file which is included into ouptut in *.targets file as MSBuild target.:

```
<Target Name="test_target" AfterTargets="BeforeBuild" Condition=" 
 Exists('testFile.config.json') ">
        <ItemGroup>
            <None Include="testFile.config.json">
                <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
            </None>
        </ItemGroup>
 </Target>
```

We know on Linux the file system is case sensitive and on Windows is vice versa.

But what we want is to search for the testFile.config.json file case insensitively with use of MSBuild.